# Getting error "cannot import name 'UNICODE_EMOJI' from 'emoji.unicode_codes' "

Tags: python, instapy

I'm trying to create an Instagram bot using InstaPy.
I'm following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/instagram-bot-python-instapy/).

When I ran:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="your username", password="your password")
session.login()
```

I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'UNICODE_EMOJI' from 'emoji.unicode_codes' (C:\Users\roeegg22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\emoji\unicode_codes\__init__.py)
```

I tried some solutions online, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 26):

This happens because instapy (or some other library) doesn't reflect the latest update to the `emoji` library. You should be able to fix it by running

```
pip uninstall emoji
pip install emoji==1.7
```

in the terminal. That way you install the version of `emoji` library that instapy is made around and the import should work.

Comment: Helped with [pilmoji](https://github.com/jay3332/pilmoji) as well

Comment: After this error I got a Clarifai.rest import error. Which lead me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596471/error-while-working-with-instapy-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-clarifa/75749692#75749692

Comment: this didnt work for me, but when i changed to pip3 install emoji==1.7, it worked.