# Error while working with instapy: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clarifai.rest'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api, modulenotfounderror, instapy

```
from instapy import InstaPy


session = InstaPy(username='name', password='password')
session.login()
```

(I use VSC) my code breaks at the first line with error:
from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp, Workflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clarifai.rest'

I tried reinstalling instapy, that specific module, but nothing changed.

Edit: Yes, I have tried reinstalling clarifai and it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried installing `clarifai` itself, as in `pip install clarifai`?

Comment: Says requirement already satisfied

Comment: Are you under virtual environment? If you are, delete it, create a new one, and start over. If you are not, you should really use it and try again.

Comment: I am not. I don't see how using a virtual enviroment would help me, but I will try.

Comment: It would help you when debugging issues like this. I suspect your problem has something to do with incorrect PYTHONPATH. With virtual environment, you have an isolated environment such that issues with import can be more easily tracked down.

Comment: @FanchenBao Still the same error. I went to the .py script that the error was referring to and # this "from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp, Workflow", since there was an error with this. My script worked, but I'm p sure that this is a wrong way to fixing things.

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6680#issuecomment-1434696781). Same problem as yours raised as an issue on instapy's repo. Might work for you.

Comment: One last thing, this project does not seem to be in a healthy shape. See [this PR](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/pull/6642). I'd be very cautious using it for anything beyond a quick proof of concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6680#issuecomment-1434696781) I tested [Franchen Bao's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9723036/fanchen-bao) comment and it worked for me. I had this error after the [emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73108683/getting-error-cannot-import-name-unicode-emoji-from-emoji-unicode-codes) error. Looks like this project is a little unstable and can only handle certain versions of each package, like [Franchen Bao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9723036/fanchen-bao) said.

```
pip uninstall clarifai
pip install clarifai==2.6.2
```

Comment: There is a fork of InstaPy, that has been updated a little bit: https://github.com/InstaPy2/InstaPy2 Don't know if that works any better though